# Create docker container with non-shareable memory and non-shareable cpus

Tags: docker

I am using Docker 17.03 -ee version

I have to create a docker container with a variable amount of memory and variable number of cpus dynamically and this hardware should not be shared between the containers.

As an example, let us consider i have

Host with 8GB memory and 4 cores.
Create a docker container (d1) with 3GB memory and 1 cpus
Create a docker container (d2) with 5GB memory and 3 cpus
Create a docker contianer (d3) with 2GB memory and 2 cpus
I have noticed that docker run takes -m flag using which i can set the memory limit and it also has --cpuset-cpus using which i can assign specific cpu cores to my container.

I was able to create d1 and d2 by using the above flags. While creating i observed that i have to take core of core management i.e i have to maintain the assignment of a cores with containers.

Can i just give number of cores and core assignment is taken care automatically ?

After creating d1 and d2, as i have used up all the available memory and cpuset, i should not be allowed to create further containers.

But if i try to create a container d4 with memory 3GB i am able to successfully create it.

How can i allocate the memory to that specific container without sharing that memory with other containers ?

Is there any already built solution which takes care of managing memory assigned with a container and cpu-cores assigned with a container ? Or Do i have to maintain this information myself and ensure that i should not create new containers when all the memory or cores are used up ?

Answer (score 0):

Since docker 1.13 you can use `--cpus` which is probably what you're looking for. Pre-1.13 you had to use `--cpu-period`and  `--cpu-quota` for which `--cpus` is actually a helper for.

To limit container to only use 1 core: `--cpus=1.0`, 2 cores `--cpus=2.0` etc. Fractions are allowed as well. But note, that neither `--cpus` nor `--cpuset-cpus` does not reserve these cpus. It simply limits how much of cpu (or which cores) can be used but it cannot disallow any other containers/processes from using same resources.

Situation is similar with memory (`--memory`). You can declare max limit and container simply cannot allocate more resources than your limit. But it does not reserve or "pre-allocate" memory in any way.

If you're looking for a way to force that kind of behavior, you should look into container orchestration solutions, like kubernetes, openshift, docker swarm and such. These solutions were created specifically for a way to easily distribute containers in your cluster while respecting total cluster resources. Then you can simply specify that for example: container X should use max 2 cores, max 500MB memory and have 2 replicas. And if your cluster does not have enough resources, container will simply be left as pending.